# Can Battlestars actually fly in the atmosphere

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In Blood And Chrome during the beginning, we see an (original style) Basestar hovering above Caprica City, and during The Plan, We see a (modern) Basestar flying through the sky at breakneck speed.

So could a Colonial Battlestar hover or fly in the atmosphere?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Colonials were not nearly as advanced as the Cylons in many ways. Yes they had developed the defense network, but the Cylons eventually even figured out how to defeat that. 

The Galactica was also a VERY retro battlestar. It's doubtful the Colonial Navy had figured out how to develop atmospheric flight for a hull that size. If you notice, most smaller craft are using retro thrusters to keep aloft. Now take that hull size times 500.

You would need some VERY LARGE and strong thrusters that would scorch a very large area, just to help keep a battlestar hull aloft!

Answer (score 17):

In the Season 3 episode *Exodus*, we see the Galactica do an FTL jump into the atmosphere of New Caprica.

As it begins to launch its Vipers, it immediately begins to drop like a rock, and only remains in atmosphere long enough to make another FTL jump to exit the atmosphere.

The fact that it fails to maintain altitude in the mean time strongly implies that Battlestars are incapable of atmospheric flight.